# Filter related entities based on common identifier of their base entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

I would like to group a list of entities by a common identifier of their base entity, select the first entity of each group and return a new list of entities. There are 3 different entities involved: GenericObject, ObjectVersion and ObjectDependency.

```
public class GenericObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectVersion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public GenericObject GenericObject { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectDependency
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObjectVersion ObjectVersion1 { get; set; }
    public ObjectVersion ObjectVersion2 { get; set; }
}
```

The sample setup looks like this:

```
GenericObject go1 = new GenericObject { Id = 1 };
GenericObject go2 = new GenericObject { Id = 2 };
GenericObject go3 = new GenericObject { Id = 3 };

ObjectVersion ov1 = new ObjectVersion { Id = 1, GenericObject = go1 };
ObjectVersion ov2 = new ObjectVersion { Id = 2, GenericObject = go2 };
ObjectVersion ov3 = new ObjectVersion { Id = 3, GenericObject = go3 };
ObjectVersion ov4 = new ObjectVersion { Id = 4, GenericObject = go1 };

List<ObjectDependency> dependencies = new List<ObjectDependency>
{
     new ObjectDependency { Name = "d1", ObjectVersion1 = ov1, ObjectVersion2 = ov2 },
     new ObjectDependency { Name = "d2", ObjectVersion1 = ov2, ObjectVersion2 = ov3 },
     new ObjectDependency { Name = "d3", ObjectVersion1 = ov4, ObjectVersion2 = ov2 }
};
```

In order to get all ObjectDependencies containing ov2, I would filter like this:

```
var ov2Dependencies = dependencies.Where(d => d.ObjectVersion1.Id == ov2.Id 
                                              || d.ObjectVersion2.Id == ov2.Id)
                                  .OrderBy(d => d.Name);
foreach (ObjectDependency dependency in ov2Dependencies)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dependency.Name);
}
// Output:
// d1
// d2
// d3
```

In order to get all ObjectVersions dependent on ov2:

```
var ov2AllDependentObjectVersions = 
             dependencies.Where(d => d.ObjectVersion1.Id == ov2.Id 
                                     || d.ObjectVersion2.Id == ov2.Id)
                         .Select(d => d.ObjectVersion1)
                         .Union(dependencies.Where(d => d.ObjectVersion1.Id == ov2.Id 
                                                       || d.ObjectVersion2.Id == ov2.Id)
                         .Select(d => d.ObjectVersion2))
                         .Where(o => o.Id != ov2.Id)
                         .OrderBy(o => o.Id);
foreach (ObjectVersion ov in ov2AllDependentObjectVersions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ov.Id);
}
// Output:
// 1
// 3
// 4
```

In order to get the latest ObjectVersions dependent on ov2 with different GenericObject:

```
var ov2LatestDependentObjectVersions = 
         dependencies.Where(d => d.ObjectVersion1.Id == ov2.Id 
                                 || d.ObjectVersion2.Id == ov2.Id)
                     .Select(d => d.ObjectVersion1)
                     .Union(dependencies.Where(d => d.ObjectVersion1.Id == ov2.Id 
                                                    || d.ObjectVersion2.Id == ov2.Id)
                     .Select(d => d.ObjectVersion2))
                     .Where(o => o.Id != ov2.Id)
                     .GroupBy(o => o.GenericObject.Id)
                     .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(o => o.Id).FirstOrDefault())
                     .OrderBy(o => o.Id);
foreach (ObjectVersion ov in ov2LatestDependentObjectVersions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ov.Id);
}
// Output:
// 3
// 4
```

How would the filtering look like, in order to achieve the following output? Basically, I would like to get the latest ObjectDependencies containing ov2 with different GenericObject. The filtering should be directly translatable into T-SQL by using IQueryable.

```
var ov2LatestDependencies = dependencies.Where(d => d.ObjectVersion1.Id == ov2.Id 
                                                     || d.ObjectVersion2.Id == ov2.Id)
                                          // ???
                                         .OrderBy(d => d.Name);
foreach (ObjectDependency dependency in ov2LatestDependencies)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dependency.Name);
}
// Output:
// d2
// d3
```

I have created a fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OZQlWO

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Edit:**

I ended up using the following solution supporting LINQ to entities based on the answer of Jason Boyd: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YSj8ki

```
var ov2LatestDependencies = dependencies.Where(d => d.ObjectVersion1.Id == ov2.Id 
                                                     || d.ObjectVersion2.Id == ov2.Id)
    .Where(x => x.ObjectVersion1.Id == ov2.Id)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        ObjectDependency = x,
        ObjectVersion = x.ObjectVersion2
    })
    .Union(
        dependencies.Where(d => d.ObjectVersion1.Id == ov2.Id 
                                                     || d.ObjectVersion2.Id == ov2.Id)
        .Where(x => x.ObjectVersion2.Id == ov2.Id)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            ObjectDependency = x,
            ObjectVersion = x.ObjectVersion1
        })
    )
    .GroupBy(x => x.ObjectVersion.GenericObject.Id)
    .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.ObjectVersion.Id).FirstOrDefault())
    .Select(x => x.ObjectDependency)
    .OrderBy(d => d.Name);
foreach (ObjectDependency dependency in ov2LatestDependencies)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dependency.Name);
}
// Output:
// d2
// d3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I took the liberty of refactoring your LINQ queries into extension methods - it makes it easier to follow what is going on:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IQueryable<ObjectDependency> WhereContainsObjectVersion(this IQueryable<ObjectDependency> source, int objectVersionId)
    {
        return
            source
            .Where(x => x.ObjectVersion1.Id == objectVersionId || x.ObjectVersion2.Id == objectVersionId);
    }

    public static IQueryable<ObjectVersion> SelectDependentObjectVersions(this IQueryable<ObjectDependency> source, int objectVersionId)
    {
        return
            source
            .WhereContainsObjectVersion(objectVersionId)
            .Select(x => x.ObjectVersion1.Id == objectVersionId ? x.ObjectVersion2 : x.ObjectVersion1);
    }

    public static IQueryable<TResult> SelectDependentObjectVersions<TResult>(this IQueryable<ObjectDependency> source, int objectVersionId, Func<ObjectDependency, ObjectVersion, TResult> selector)
    {
        return
            source
            .WhereContainsObjectVersion(objectVersionId)
            .Select(x => x.ObjectVersion1.Id == objectVersionId ? selector(x, x.ObjectVersion2) : selector(x, x.ObjectVersion1));
    }

    public static IQueryable<ObjectVersion> SelectByLatestDistinctGenericObject(this IQueryable<ObjectVersion> source)
    {
        return
            source
            .GroupBy(x => x.GenericObject.Id)
            .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Id).FirstOrDefault());
    }

    public static IQueryable<ObjectDependency> SelectByLatestDistinctGenericObject(this IQueryable<ObjectDependency> source, int objectVersionId)
    {
        return
            source
            .SelectDependentObjectVersions(objectVersionId, (x, y) => new { ObjectDependency = x, ObjectVersion = y })
            .GroupBy(x => x.ObjectVersion.GenericObject.Id)
            .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.ObjectVersion.Id).FirstOrDefault())
            .Select(x => x.ObjectDependency);
    }
}
```

Then you can call them in the following way (I commented out portions of your LINQ queries and inserted my extension methods so that you can see what portion of each query the extension methods are replacing):

```
// Get all ObjectDependencies containing ov2
// Output:
// d1
// d2
// d3
Console.WriteLine("Get all ObjectDependencies containing ov2");
IEnumerable<ObjectDependency> ov2Dependencies =
    dependencies
    //.Where(d => d.ObjectVersion1.Id == ov2.Id || d.ObjectVersion2.Id == ov2.Id)
    .WhereContainsObjectVersion(ov2.Id)
    .OrderBy(d => d.Name);
foreach (ObjectDependency dependency in ov2Dependencies)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dependency.Name);
}

// Get all ObjectVersions dependent on ov2
// Output:
// 1
// 3
// 4
Console.WriteLine("Get all ObjectVersions dependent on ov2");
IEnumerable<ObjectVersion> ov2AllDependentObjectVersions =
    dependencies
    //.Where(d => d.ObjectVersion1.Id == ov2.Id || d.ObjectVersion2.Id == ov2.Id)
    //.Select(d => d.ObjectVersion1)
    //.Union(dependencies.Where(d => d.ObjectVersion1.Id == ov2.Id || d.ObjectVersion2.Id == ov2.Id)
    //.Select(d => d.ObjectVersion2))
    //.Where(o => o.Id != ov2.Id)
    .SelectDependentObjectVersions(ov2.Id)
    .OrderBy(o => o.Id);
foreach (ObjectVersion ov in ov2AllDependentObjectVersions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ov.Id);
}

// Get newest ObjectVersions dependent on ov2 with different GenericObject
// Output:
// 3
// 4
Console.WriteLine("Get newest ObjectVersions dependent on ov2 with different GenericObject");
IEnumerable<ObjectVersion> ov2NewestDependentObjectVersions =
    dependencies
    //.Where(d => d.ObjectVersion1.Id == ov2.Id || d.ObjectVersion2.Id == ov2.Id)
    //.Select(d => d.ObjectVersion1)
    //.Union(dependencies.Where(d => d.ObjectVersion1.Id == ov2.Id || d.ObjectVersion2.Id == ov2.Id)
    //.Select(d => d.ObjectVersion2))
    //.Where(o => o.Id != ov2.Id)
    //.GroupBy(o => o.GenericObject.Id)
    //.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(o => o.Id).FirstOrDefault())
    .SelectDependentObjectVersions(ov2.Id)
    .SelectByLatestDistinctGenericObject()
    .OrderBy(o => o.Id);
foreach (ObjectVersion ov in ov2NewestDependentObjectVersions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ov.Id);
}

// Get newest ObjectDependencies containing ov2 with different GenericObject
// Output:
// d2
// d3
Console.WriteLine("Get newest ObjectDependencies containing ov2 with different GenericObject");
IEnumerable<ObjectDependency> ov2NewestDependencies =
    dependencies
    //.Where(d => d.ObjectVersion1.Id == ov2.Id || d.ObjectVersion2.Id == ov2.Id)
    // ???
    .SelectByLatestDistinctGenericObject(ov2.Id)
    .OrderBy(d => d.Name);
foreach (ObjectDependency dependency in ov2NewestDependencies)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dependency.Name);
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, but I think this will not translate very well into IQueryable / T-SQL respectively?

Comment: I missed the `iqueryable` tag.  In any event, I don't think it matters.  I am pretty sure that you can just change all the `IEnumerable` types to `IQueryable` (the parameters and return types) and it should work fine.

Comment: @nilr - Updated answer based on new information.  Replaced all the `IEnumerable` with `IQueryable` and removed iterator blocks.  I believe that should work for you.